# Gtest errors when compiling workspace

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some time now (due to some update, probably), I have problems with GTest when compiling a workspace.

When installing GTest on the system, libgtest.so and libgtest_main.so are created, and cmake finds them. They are static or dynamic depending on how it is installed. Everithing is OK (I suppose)

When compiling a workspace, I always have the same error:

```
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy

-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/paco/ros_ws/tests_ws/build/test_results
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built 
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:372 (add_library):   add_library cannot create imported target "gtest" because another target   with the same name already exists. Call Stack (most recent call first):   /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:147 (include)   /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)   CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:374 (add_library):   add_library cannot create imported target "gtest_main" because another   target with the same name already exists. Call Stack (most recent call first):   /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:147 (include)   /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)   CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)
   
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.11
```

This is caused because in /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:363,  libgtest.so is required to be built, even if it exists in the system, producing that error.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is it misconfigured in my system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299791/gtest-errors-when-compiling-workspace/) by [fmrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/13346/fmrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2018-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-06**:
What version of the package `ros-kinetic-catkin` do you have installed?

**Comment by [fmrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/13346/fmrico/) on 2018-08-06**:
0.7.11-0xenial-20180222-175501-0800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to update `ros-kinetic-catkin` to at least version 0.7.12 (see https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/kinetic-devel/CHANGELOG.rst#0712-2018-05-01).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fmrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/13346/fmrico/) on 2018-08-06**:
Yes, it fixed my problem :) Thanks!!!

The point is that, as far as I know, 0.7.11 is the current version for kinetic xenial, and it seems to be broken...

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-06**:
Since other Xenial systems don't face the problem I would assume there is a difference on your system. Do you have a custom version of gtest / googletest installed? Anyway the latest version of `catkin` should become available in Kinetic in a future sync.

**Comment by [fmrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/13346/fmrico/) on 2018-08-07**:
It is an updated xenial distro, and gtest is installed using the libgtest-dev package in the distro (1.7.0-4). Obviously, there is a particularity, but I do not figure out which.

**Comment by [roboticom314](https://answers.ros.org/users/26759/roboticom314/) on 2018-08-10**:
What is the process of updating ros-kinetic-catkin to 0.7.12 since there's only one candidate (0.7.11) to install with apt install?

I suppose to build from source and install. What's the preferred install location?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-10**:
Version 0.7.14 has recently been released into Kinetic. The status page (http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=catkin) shows that it has been built already (first green square), once all other Kinetic packages have been rebuild it becomes available in the testing repo...

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-10**:
(second square, currently blue since it has still the old version) - that should happen within 24h. After that it becomes available in the main repo when the "ROS Boss" decides to sync which is announced on Discourse (usually within a couple of weeks).

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-10**:
The Debian package is in the `building` repo (http://repositories.ros.org/ubuntu/building/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-catkin/) if you want to install it ahead of time. In this case that should be fine - in other cases I wouldn't recommend it.